# How to change route/view from a link inside a templateUrl in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the correct configuration for my routes here in my app.js file:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "views/mainPage/mainPage.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/financing", {templateUrl: "views/financing/financing.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/photoGallery", {templateUrl: "views/photoGallery/photoGallery.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
});
```

And I have my index.html here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<body ng-app="hlWiki">
<div ng-view ng-controller="PageCtrl">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How would I create a link inside of the financing template html file to change the view/route to the photoGallery template html?

I can do this routing just fine from index.html, but not from within the template html files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the route with `$location` in your controller:

```
$location.path('/photoGallery');
```

This can be called *onclick* or on every event you want.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: It was a pleasure to help :)